# What is the equivalent of Perl's (<>) in Python? fileinput doesn't work as expected

Tags: python, perl, file-io, file, command-line-arguments

In Perl one uses:

```
while (<>) {
    # process files given as command line arguments
}
```

In Python I found:

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input():
    process(line)
```

But, what happens when the file given in the command line does NOT exist?

`python test.py test1.txt test2.txt filenotexist1.txt filenotexist2.txt test3.txt` was given as the argument.

I tried various ways of using `try: except: nextfile`, but I couldn't seem to make it work.

For the above commandline, the script should run for `test1-3.txt` but just go to next file silent when the file is NOT found.

Perl does this very well. I have searched this all over the net, but I couldn't find the answer to this one anywhere.

Comment: "but just go to next file silent when the file is NOT found."?  Really?  Why?  If the file doesn't exist, why shouldn't the entire thing break?

Comment: @S.Lott: Think unix command line utilities such as grep. They operate on valid arguments, but just give warnings on non-existent files, and the warnings don't cause the whole command to abort, although it does make the command exit with an error status. That said, perl is not "silent" on non-existent files, it also gives warnings.

Comment: @S.Lott There are quite valid cases, e.g. reading through a set of config files and ignoring cases where some of them don't exist.

Comment: @S.Lott: Whether a nonexistent file represents a fatal error or not is a per-application issue. Some applications should abort on a non-existent file; for instance, a daemon might choose to abort if its configuration file isn't present, because the configuration file is required. Other applications, however, might not; a missing configuration file, for instance, might just mean the application should use default values. Knowing how to handle both situations is useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import sys
import os

for f in sys.argv[1:]:
    if os.path.exists(f):
        for line in open(f).readlines():
            process(line)
```

Comment: thanks for this.. is there any other answer with the simplest keystrokes..
in Perl.. while (<>) { } << only required a few characters..

any similar shortcuts with python.

Comment: @ihightower Yes. Take my method, put it into a module and import it. The all you need is `for line in read_lines():`. Python doesn't aim for obscure operators with minimal keystrokes though, so you won't find something as terse as Perl's `<>` but you *could* rename the method to something like `rl()` to get `for l in rl():` if you absolutely must.

Comment: This fails to take account the other possible errors, like file not readable, file is a directory, text file locked, etc.  I genuinely agree with the OP that if `fileinput` wants to be useful, it should offer control over this aspect of its operation.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this;

```
import sys

for f in sys.argv[1:]:
    try:
        data = open(f).readlines()
        process(data)
    except IOError:
        continue
```

Answer (score 3):

Turning @Brian's answer into a generator, and catching `IOError` rather than testing for existence which is more Pythonic and then printing a warning to stderr on failure:

```
import sys

def read_files(files = None):
  if not files:
    files = sys.argv[1:]
  for file in files:
    try:
      for line in open(file):
        yield line
    except IOError, e:
      print >>sys.stderr, 'Warning:', e

for line in read_files():
  print line,
```

Output (the file `baz` does not exist):

```
$ python read_lines.py foo bar baz
line 1 of foo
line 2 of foo
line 1 of bar
line 2 of bar
Warning: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'baz'
```

You might want to put in a little effort tidying up the error message, but it might not be worth the effort.

Comment: Note, however, that catching `IOError` will trap and ignore more than just "file doesn't exist" problems. If the file exists, but isn't readable, you'll never know. This may be fine, of course, depending on the application; however, if you want to distinguish between nonexistent files and errors reading existing files, catching and ignoring `IOError` isn't the way to go.

Comment: @Brian Indeed, but in this case I'd say it's an improvement over just "file doesn't exist".

Comment: No argument. As I said, it's an application-dependent decision. It should be an *explicit* decision, either way.

Comment: Do what perl does. Don't ignore errors, print them to stdout.

Comment: @runrig Not what was asked for, but it's a valid point. I'll go with stderr though.

Comment: @Brian OP is aiming to mimic Perl here. Perl doesn't fall over when it can't read a file, nor does my solution.

Comment: stderr...I meant stderr :-) That said, can you print the actual system error message?

Comment: With version 2.4.6 and 2.7.1, I get "No attribute 'msg'". Plain 'e' or e[1] or 'sys.exc_info()[1]' works though.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve your problem with fileinput module as follows:

```
import fileinput

input = fileinput.input()
while True:
    try:
        process(input.next())
    except IOError:
        input.nextfile()
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

Unfortunately you can't use for loop because the IOException breaks it.

Comment: +1 for this!  The `except` clause should usefully also do something like `except IOError, e: sys.stderr.write("%s: %s: %s\n" % (sys.argv[0], input.filename(), os.strerror(e.errno)))` before the `nextfile()`.

Comment: +1 thanks JooMing, tripleee - useful to have a solution that sticks with fileinput (quick and easy change to my existing code)

Answer (score 1):

I tried to implement @VGE's suggestion, but my attempt turned out not to be too elegant.  I'd appreciate any suggestions for how to improve this.

```
import sys, fileinput, errno, os

class nosuchfile:
    def readlines(foo, bar):
        return []
    def close(arg):
        pass

EXITCODE=0

def skip_on_error (filename, mode):
    """Function to pass in as fileinput.input(openhook=...) hook function.
    Instead of give up on the first error, skip the rest of the file and
    continue with the next file in the input list.

    In case of an error from open() an error message is printed to standard
    error and the global variable EXITCODE gets overwritten by a nonzero
    value.
    """
    global EXITCODE
    try:
        return open(filename, mode)
    except IOError, e:
        sys.stderr.write ("%s: %s: %s\n" % (sys.argv[0], filename, os.strerror(e.errno)))
        EXITCODE = 1
        return nosuchfile()

def main ():
    do_stuff(fileinput.input(openhook=skip_on_error))
    return EXITCODE
```

Both the placeholder dummy filehandle class `nosuchfile` and the global variable `EXITCODE` are pretty serious warts.  I tried to figure out how to pass in a reference to a locally scoped exitcode variable, but gave up.

This also fails to handle errors which happen while reading, but the majority of error cases seem to happen in `open` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Simple, explicit, and silent:

```
import fileinput
from os.path import exists
import sys

for line in fileinput.input(files=filter(exists, sys.argv[1:])):
    process(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe You can play with the openhook parameter to control not existing file.